# How to highlight or mark changed lines in Vim?

Tags: vim

In many IDEs and editors, the lines which have been changed since file load can be marked or highlighted. How can I do this in Vim?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VIM highlight changed lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340404/vim-highlight-changed-lines)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Vim - highlight changed lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340404/vim-highlight-changed-lines)