# Taking a quick look at DiffOrig, then switching back

Tags: vim, editor

I've discovered this great command from the documentation:

```
 command DiffOrig vert new | set bt=nofile | r # | 0d_ | diffthis
    \ | wincmd p | diffthis
```

So I've come up with this:

```
command DiffOrig vert new | set bt=nofile | r # | 0d_ | diffthis | wincmd p | diffthis | wincmd p
map <Leader>do :DiffOrig<cr>
map <leader>dc :q<cr>:diffoff!<cr>
```

The problem is, when I se `\dc`, it will jump back to the beginning of the file, not where I left it prior to issuing `\do`. How to fix this?

Please try this yourself, see what the problems are and how to fix them. And tell me how to fix them too :-)

Comment: I like using `:bd` instead of `:q`, since it actually deletes the scratch buffer, instead of just closing the window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try:

```
command DiffOrig let g:diffline = line('.') | vert new | set bt=nofile | r # | 0d_ | diffthis | :exe "norm! ".g:diffline."G" | wincmd p | diffthis | wincmd p
nnoremap <Leader>do :DiffOrig<cr>
nnoremap <leader>dc :q<cr>:diffoff<cr>:exe "norm! ".g:diffline."G"<cr>
```

Comment: Yes, I know this is old, but I found an issue, and have a solution for  said issue. If you resource your ~/.vimrc while vim is running, you get an error about the command already existing. To remove that error,  add a '!' to 'command so it looks like `command! DiffOrg....` (etc).

Answer (score 2):

You can `:q` in the window you want to close, and then `:diffoff` to turn off the diff formatting in the remaining window. Not sure if it can be done in one command.

Comment: I prefer to do `:diffoff!` as it will `:diffoff` all windows.

Comment: Instead of `:q` in the windows that you want to close, you can also `on` (short for `only`) in the window that you want to keep!

Answer (score 1):

To close the diff windows and go back to the file you were editing, you could try adding this to your .vimrc file:

if !exists(":DiffOff")
  command DiffOff diffoff <bar> only
endif

Then enter :DiffOff to close the diff windows.