# vim plugin for indicating changed lines

Tags: vim

I'm looking for a plugin that shows changed lines in vim as in Visual Studio:

[image]

Looks like [vim-gitgutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) and [vim-signify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-signify/) only work for files under version control. Had tried [changesPlugin](https://github.com/chrisbra/changesPlugin) but there is error on my vim ([issue #16](https://github.com/chrisbra/changesPlugin/issues/16)).

Also tried `DiffOrig` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340404/vim-highlight-changed-lines), but it is opening a split window instead of showing the indicator bar.

Comment: It looks like the author goofed. Just revert his last commit and I imagine it would work. (its 6 days old at the moment) It should be fixed once he notices the error. (He's pretty active, so he should notice soon)

Comment: @FDinoff indeed, he had fixed the issue already. It's a great plugin, exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Christian Brabandt FTW!